# IIS 8.0 HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp-classic

Guys i'm constantly facing this problem, I've tried a lots of tricks but all in vein. Can any body help me about this problem please. All static pages are working but when i open any dynamic page it come up with this error. I'm using C# using IIS 8.0. I'd be very obliged if someone could help me please.

HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

Most likely causes:
The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different handler.

Things you can try:
If you want to serve this content as a static file, add an explicit MIME map.

Detailed Error Information:
Module             StaticFileModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler            StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070032

Requested URL      [localhost:58273/quote.cshtml]
Physical Path      F:\ORG\quote.cshtml
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      [C:\Users\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\ORG2]

More Information:
Sometimes preconditions and a wildcard MIME map can unintentionally cause serving script source.
View more information »

Answer (score 6):

Try selecting ASP.NET4.5 options

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This solved the same issue for me! In my case I had to turn on the feature "ASP.NET 4.8" in Windows and also set my application pool's .NET CLR version to "v4.0".